# Generate call to generic method in runtime

Tags: c#, generics, reflection.emit

Goal: generate method like this in runtime:

```cs
public void InsertOnSubmit<T>(IQueryable<T> q, T o) where T : class, new()
{
    (q as Table<T>).InsertOnSubmit(o);
}
```

My current code for this is:

```cs
var tb = mb.DefineType("DatabaseDataRepository");

// define & implement other methods, etc

/* Define InsertOnSubmit<> method */
var insertOnSubmitMethod = tb.DefineMethod("InsertOnSubmit",
     MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Virtual |
                    MethodAttributes.NewSlot);
var genericInput = insertOnSubmitMethod.DefineGenericParameters("T")[0];
                genericInput.SetGenericParameterAttributes(GenericParameterAttributes.ReferenceTypeConstraint | GenericParameterAttributes.DefaultConstructorConstraint);
                insertOnSubmitMethod.SetParameters(typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(genericInput), genericInput);
insertOnSubmitMethod.SetReturnType(null);

/* Implement InsertOnSubmit<> method */
var saveMethodGen = insertOnSubmitMethod.GetILGenerator();
saveMethodGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // push first argument (collection)
saveMethodGen.Emit(OpCodes.Isinst, typeof(Table<>).MakeGenericType(genericInput)); // cast first argument to Table<>
saveMethodGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2); // push second argument (element)
saveMethodGen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Table<>).GetMethod("InsertOnSubmit")); // insert second argument to table
saveMethodGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // return from InsertOnSubmit method
```

But running this method on generated instance I get:
`An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)` with stack `` at DatabaseDataRepository.InsertOnSubmit[T](IQueryable`1 , T ) ``

I suspect there is something wrong in this line `saveMethodGen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Table<>).GetMethod("InsertOnSubmit"));` - it should really be something like `typeof(Table<>).MakeGenericType(genericInput).GetMethod("InsertOnSubmit")` - but this throws `NotSupportedException`

Any hints to tackle this?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to generate a method at runtime, rather than just create the method with type parameters, as your example?

Comment: I need to generate instance of interface in runtime. Rules for generating code could be (slightly) different depending on caller - this is outside of the scope of a question.

Comment: @AlexanderBortnik I'd say it was definitely inside the scope of the question as it could be a manifestation of the "XY" Problem... You're asking how to solve X, but you actually want to solve Y - which isn't present in the question at hand :)

Comment: Sounds like a potential [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  You may want to rethink your approach.  I've used a *lot* of generics and reflection for some vastly generic projects and have never had to do what you're asking.

Comment: Well, in some cases I'd want to add calls to logger in this method, in some not, etc. So implementation could be different in depending on the caller, but call to "InsertOnSubmit" is needed anyway. I left these details outside the question.

Comment: That's very vague to someone that doesn't know what you're actually trying to do, so I can't make any real valid suggestions, but it really does sound like you're taking a convoluted approach to something that may be as simple as an overloaded method or optional parameters.  It also potentially sounds like IoC may fix your issue, where the caller defines what objects the callee uses, but yeah, too vague to really help.  Good luck, either way :)

Comment: @thehennyy I tried that - see the last lines of my question. It throws ``NotSupportedException``

Comment: You are right, that detail is somehow hidden, you have to use the static `System.Reflection.Emit.Typebuilder.GetMethod` method to create the correctly typed `MethodInfo`. Like: `Typebuilder.GetMethod(typeof(Table<>).MakeGenericType(genericInput), typeof(Table<>).GetMethod("InsertOnSubmit"))`

Comment: @thehennyy Great, thanks a million, this works! Could you please post it as an answer, so I can upvote?

Comment: @Archer Thanks for your input. I also considered that, but the path with auto-generated code seems more flexible given the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the static `System.Reflection.Emit.Typebuilder.GetMethod` method to create the correctly typed `MethodInfo`.

The msdn states:

> Returns the method of the specified constructed generic type that corresponds to the specified method of the generic type definition.

In your case that would be:

```
Typebuilder.GetMethod(typeof(Table<>).MakeGenericType(genericInput), typeof(Table<>).GetMethod("InsertOnSubmit"))
```